# TFS: is it possible to checkout code while excluding certain changesets?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

My gut feeling is that this is not possible, but what I'd like to do is this: checkout my code from TFS but exclude a specific changeset in that checkout. If it's not possible to do this directly, is there some obscure TFS feature that might let me remove a changeset from an already checked out set of code?

I'm more curious than anything, so if it's not possible, it's not the end of the world.

**Afterthought:**
If it's not possible to do what I did above, is it possible to checkout all code **before** a certain changeset?

Comment: Did you really mean "Check out" orr should it be "Get specific version"?
Why would you need to check out like that?

Comment: "Get specific version". Completely forgot about that, and I must have missed it several times while I was looking for a way to do this, haha. Just one of those days, I suppose ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to exclude changeset. However you can get all source up to specific changeset, label, date...

In the TFS explorer you can say "Get specific version" and then select version type "changeset" which will give you everything up to and including that changeset.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [woodwardweb.com](http://www.woodwardweb.com/WindowsLiveWriter/TFSTopTip11Removingsourcecontrolfilesfro_B380/get_changeset_1[2].png))</sub>

Comment: I completely forgot about that, haha. Thanks :-)